# return group_concat data as array

Tags: php, mysql

I want to return values I retrieve from the db using group_concat as an array of data. Is it possible to do this in the mysql query? Or do I need to explode the data into an array?

```
GROUP_CONCAT(sh.hold_id) as holds
```

returns this

```
[holds] => 3,4
```

I want it to return:

```
[holds] => array(3,4)
```

Comment: You need to explode the data into an array, using php: `$holds = explode(',', $holds);` because mysql has no concept of array-type for data.

Comment: Why to use group_concat in such cases, just `select sh.hold_id` and push them in an array.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As I said in my comment: you need to [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the data into an array, using php code like this:

```
$holds = explode(',', $holds);
```

because mysql has no concept of array-type for data.

Answer (score 8):

This is possible since **MySQL 5.7.22** using the JSON_ARRAYAGG() method

Read more: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg

Example:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(category.slug) as categories From categories
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need to do it on the MySQL level, and then you may probably parse it to an object.
You can do the following

```
SELECT CONCAT("[", GROUP_CONCAT(category.name), "]") AS categories
From categories
```

Answer (score 4):

MySQL has no concept of arrays. Therefore it is not able to return an array. It is up to your processing code (here the php scripts) to convert the concatenated notation into a php array.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to return mysql JSON array like so,

```
json_array(GROUP_CONCAT(sh.hold_id)) as holds
```

Refer [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-array) for further info.

Comment: This would return `["val1,val2"]` instead of `["val1","val2"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
CONCAT('["', GROUP_CONCAT(sh.hold_id separator '","'), '"]') as holds
```

will return

```
["val1","val2"]
```