# convert PDO resultset array to accessible Array PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I am using PDO statement like below

```
$sql1 = "select food_typename from foodtypes WHERE 1";
$statement1 = $pdo->prepare($sql1);
$statement1->execute();
$results1 = $statement1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($results1);
```

I am getting output as below:

```
Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [food_typename] => Punjabi
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [food_typename] => Indian
    )
 )
```

I want it be like

```
Array('Punjabi','Indian')
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2):

If you're running PHP >= 5.5

```
$results = array_column($results1, 'food_typename');
```

If you're running earlier versions of PHP,

```
$results = array_map(
    $results1, 
    function($value) {
        return $value['food_typename'];
    }
);
```

Though I don't really understand why you can't work with the original array in the first place

Comment: @Jake - I have a suspicion that the OP wants to use a foreach loop to present the results, and doesn't understand how to access values in a multidimensional array, so the whole question is pretty moot anyway

Comment: @mark baker .. I am not finding out anyway to iterate through this multidimensional array as i have to use in_array() function to detect values.. So decided to go via simple array

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map` but `foreach` works just as well and actually runs faster than `array_map` for cases like this:

```
// Set a test array.
$results1 = array();
$results1[] = array('food_typename' => 'Punjabi');
$results1[] = array('food_typename' => 'Indian');

// Set the final reults in an array.
$results_final = array();
foreach ($results1 as $results1_value) {
  $results_final[] = $results1_value['food_typename'];
}

// Dump the line array for debugging.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($results_final);
echo '</pre>';
```

And the output of that would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Punjabi
    [1] => Indian
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The query way:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(food_typename), 1 AS dummy
FROM foodtypes
GROUP BY dummy
```

Then you need to retrieve the first field of the only record you will get back from mysql, and turn it into an array: see [return group_concat data as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745070/return-group-concat-data-as-array)